# python mysql write error

Tags: python, mysql, try-catch

I have a script that works taking in a csv file and output to a mysql database.  Everything works well, but with a new file, I'm getting an odd error that is not getting caught by a try/error sequence, which is just below -

```
try:
rtn = csr.execute (strg)

db.commit()
print "Successfully processed record " + str(row_index) + " with entryno=" +     
entryno

except mdb.Warning, e:
print "Warning %d %s " % (e.args[0] , e.args[1])
print "Successfully processed record " + str(row_index)

except mdb.Error , e:
print "Error %d %s " % (e.args[0] , e.args[1])
print "Failed to process record " + str(row_index)
#       sys.exit() (or what you want to do if an error occurs)
```

on syserr, I get the following mixed between my sysout -

```
Successfully processed record 3220 witload-pur2.py:135: Warning: Data truncated for column 'price' at row 1
  rtn = csr.execute (strg)
  h entryno=579848
```

I thought it was an error in the record (though I couldn't find it in the record or the ones surrounding it).  How do I catch this and fix it??

Answer (score 2):

This warning means that the `price` column is set to a data type that is not big enough for the value you are trying to hold. How is the `price` column declared?